Unable to get dotnet information to initialize template engine host
enter image description here
Whenever I tried to create project using C# dev kit in VS Code, I get this error. I am using VS Code version 1.90.
I have installed .NET SDK and C# Dev Kit v1.7.22

I ran into this problem today, using a MacBook Pro (Intel). All you have to do is restart the computer and then re-launch VSCode, then create a new .NET project again.
